# Reload widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API that returns content and I put this content in a `GridView.builder` to allow pagination.

I have architected the page in such a way that I have a FutureBuilder on a stateless widget and when the snapshot is done I then pass the snapshot data to a stateful widget to build the grid.

It is all working fine, however I want now to implement a functionality that allows me to reload the widget by placing a reload icon when snapshot has error and on click reloading widget. How can I accomplish this?
The following is my FutureBuilder on my Stateless widget:

```
return new FutureBuilder<List<Things>>(
    future: apiCall(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshots.hasError)
        return //Reload Icon
      switch (snapshots.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        case ConnectionState.done:
          return StatefulWidhet(things: snapshot.data);
        default:
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to lift the state up. The whole loading concept is abstracted by the `FutureBuilder`, but because you don't want to do one-time-loading, that's not the right abstraction layer for you. That means, you'll need to implement the "waiting for the future to complete and then build stuff" yourself in order to be able to trigger the loading repeatedly.

For example, you could put everything in a `StatefulWidget` and have `isLoading`, `data` and `error` properties and set these correctly.

Because this is probably a recurring task, you could even create a widget to handle that for you:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Reloader<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<T> Function() loader;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T data) dataBuilder;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, dynamic error) errorBuilder;

  const Reloader({
    Key key,
    this.loader,
    this.dataBuilder,
    this.errorBuilder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ReloaderState<T>();

  static of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<ReloaderState>());
}

class ReloaderState<T> extends State<Reloader<T>> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  T data;
  dynamic error;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    reload();
  }

  Future<void> reload() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
      data = null;
      error = null;
    });
    try {
      data = await widget.loader();
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error;
    } finally {
      setState(() => isLoading = false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return (data != null)
        ? widget.dataBuilder(context, data)
        : widget.errorBuilder(context, error);
  }
}
```

Then, you can just do

```dart
Reloader(
  loader: apiCall,
  dataBuilder: (context, data) {
    return DataWidget(things: data);
  },
  errorBuilder: (context, error) {
    return ...
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => Reloader.of(context).reload(),
        child: Text(reload),
      ),
    ...;
  },
)
```

Also, I wrote a package for that case which has some more features built-in and uses a controller-based architecture instead of searching the state through `Reload.of(context)`: [flutter_cached](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached)

With it, you could just do the following:

In a state, create a `CacheController` (although you don't need to cache things):

```dart
var controller = CacheController(
  fetcher: apiCall,
  saveToCache: () {},
  loadFromCache: () {
    throw 'There is no cache!';
  },
),
```

Then, you could use that `controller` to build a `CachedBuilder` in the `build` method:

```dart
CachedBuilder(
  controller: controller,
  errorScreenBuilder: (context, error) => ...,
  builder: (context, items) => ...,
  ...
),
```

When the reload button is pressed, you can simply call `controller.fetch()`. And you'll also get some cool things like pull-to-refresh on top.

Comment: Thanks @Marcel, let me try this

Comment: i can replace   final Future<T> Function() loader with my API call?

Comment: Exactly. See the `Reloader` usage example, where we pass in an `apiCall` for the `loader`. That would be an asynchronous function that returns the data from the server.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, however i am getting a trier calling reload on null, i dont know if its my architecture, , i have a main page with tabs, the tabs are stateful widgets what i am trying to do is call the reload function from my main.dart, getting the context of the reloader widget is proving to be somewhat hard

Comment: Oh, I see. When calling `Reloader.of(context)`, you need to pass in a context that is below the `Reloader`. But the context was from outside of the `Reloader`. I edited the code so that the inner context is used. By the way, you can always get a reference to the current `context` by wrapping it in a `Builder` widget.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Marcel, i am gonna try that out, thanks

Comment: Thanks Marcel, however the above error (trying to call reload on null) still persisted so i decided to go with a stream builder and the block pattern. The implimentation works to a certain degree but now the stream builder is always in connection state waiting. i have tried workarounds like setting a timer and after a couple of secconds pass while the connection state is still waiting then we show a refresh widget, the problem is even when the snapshot is active and data is shown, the timer still invokes and a refresh widget is still shown after the couple of seconds

Comment: That seems to be out of the scope of this question then. If you encounter any specific other errors and need help, I'd advise you to open a new question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help